# How to merge two arrays from SQL query?

Tags: php, sql, arrays, associative-array, array-merge

I've got following two queries :

```
SELECT date( FROM_UNIXTIME( user_reg_date ) ) 'Current Date', COUNT( * ) 'registered_user'
FROM users
WHERE user_reg_date >=1341100800
AND user_reg_date <=1374451200
GROUP BY date( FROM_UNIXTIME( user_reg_date ) )

SELECT date( FROM_UNIXTIME( user_last_login ) ) 'Current Date', COUNT( * ) 'logged_in_user'
FROM users
WHERE user_last_login >=1341100800
AND user_last_login <=1374451200
GROUP BY date( FROM_UNIXTIME( user_last_login ) )
```

Now I want merge the two arrays which I got from the above query and each array element should be of the following form.

```
date = > array(registered_user, logged_in_user)
```

Can anyone help me in this regard? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do a very simple `UNION ALL` and group by date later with a `SUM` to get the values;

```sql
SELECT DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)) date, 
       SUM(registered_user) registered_user, 
       SUM(logged_in_user) logged_in_user
FROM (
  SELECT user_reg_date date, 1 registered_user, 0 logged_in_user FROM users
  UNION ALL
  SELECT user_last_login,    0 registered_user, 1 logged_in_user FROM users
) a
WHERE date >= 1341100800 AND date <= 1374451200
GROUP BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(date));
```

Comment: Thank you so much one again. Your query really did the magic for me. I tworked perfectly as per my requirement. I've accepted your answer and upvoted it also.

Comment: :As like above query I want to fetch the same record counts whose reg_date and last_login date falls within current week, last week and last two weeks. How could I write these things in WHERE condition?

Comment: Can't test, but `WHERE YEARWEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)) = YEARWEEK(NOW())`, `WHERE YEARWEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)) = YEARWEEK(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)` and `WHERE YEARWEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)) >= YEARWEEK(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)` respectively would seem promising.

Answer (score 2):

Use `UNION` like

```
SELECT date( FROM_UNIXTIME( user_reg_date ) ) 'Current Date', COUNT( * ) 'registered_user'
FROM users
WHERE user_reg_date >=1341100800
AND user_reg_date <=1374451200
GROUP BY date( FROM_UNIXTIME( user_reg_date ) )

UNION

SELECT date( FROM_UNIXTIME( user_last_login ) ) 'Current Date', COUNT( * )   'logged_in_user'
FROM users
WHERE user_last_login >=1341100800
AND user_last_login <=1374451200
GROUP BY date( FROM_UNIXTIME( user_last_login ) )
```

But careful with the duplicate columns that these two tables have.Try to call them using table object like

```
table1.id,table2.id
```

Consider that `id` has exists in both the tables.

Comment: I tried this but it gives only current_date and registered_user. Actually I want both the counts in an array.

Comment: You forgot to write like this with 'as'  COUNT( * ) as 'registered_user'

Comment: @phpLover: What does prevent you to do so? I can not see any code in your question that shows what you've actually tried, so it's a bit unfair to let other place guessed answers only then to tell them you tried that already. Don't you think so?